# Unable to add another email in iMessage or login with a different iCloud account on iOS 11

Tags: ios, icloud, messages

I upgraded to iOS 11 today, and I am no longer able to add another email in Messages. And when I sign out of Messages, I can no longer use a different iCloud account (i.e., iOS will not allow me to edit the email address in the login form).

This option in the circle is no longer available
[image: Add Another Email... is no longer available]

Is there another way to add another email to Messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@oa- was close.

To use a different Apple ID for Messages

1. Sign out of iCloud on the device
2. Go to Messages setting (Settings > Messages)
3. Login to Messages with the alternate emai
4. Go back and sign-in to iCloud with your main Apple ID

Answer (score 1):

To use another iCloud account, please go to

**Settings > Messages > Send & Receive** and tap 'Apple ID: >your Apple ID<' > Sign Out.

You also need to sign out of iCloud in Settings > iCloud in order to use another Apple ID for messages/iMessage.

Now you can sign in with another Apple ID.

To add another email address you be reached with using iMessage, [manage your Apple ID](https://appleid.apple.com/#!&page=signin) in a browser and add another email address there.

Comment: It used to be you can sign-in with a different Apple ID in Messages without having to sign out completely or add another email to an existing Apple ID.